# Image over image in stage table and verticaly align inner table

Tags: libgdx, stage

I am making simple libgdx game and now I want to put shade over inactive achievements. Is there any possibility to have image over image in table cell?

Now I have something like this and first element from inner table is still vertically centered. Nothing changes after adding `outerTable.top();`

```
    outerTable = new Table();
    innerTable = new Table();
    innerTable.row().width(achie_width).height(achie_height);
    innerTable.add(new Image(ltm.assets.kurtyna));
    innerTable.setFillParent(true);
    scrollPane = new ScrollPane(innerTable); 
    outerTable.setPosition(0, 0);
    outerTable.setSize(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(),Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    outerTable.debug();
    outerTable.top();
    outerTable.add(scrollPane).fill().expand();
    stage.addActor(outerTable);
```

Comment: I didn't ktow that stack exist, thanks.

Comment: Do you know how can i align table in scroll pane to top edge of screen ?

Comment: You'd do the layouting via a Table. `Table layout = new Table(); layout.setFillParent(true); table.top();`

Comment: I add outerTable.top() and nothing change.